# Jenkins building latest commit, not GitHub post-commit hook specified commit

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Jenkins seems to build unbuilt branches rather than the branch specified on the GitHub post commit hook.  How do I tell Jenkins to build the branch specified in the GitHub post-commit hook -- even if it built it previously?

For example, let's assume develop branch is 20 commits behind feature/coolness, feature/coolness is on git hash 123abc, and now I merge develop in such that develop and feature/coolness are on git hash 123abc.  Meanwhile, feature/irrelevant has new commits such that the latest commit on any branch is feature/irrelevant.  I push develop branch to GitHub, and Jenkins builds feature/irrelevant instead of develop.

GitHub is set to trigger Jenkins via [post-commit hook](http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github), and on a commit to GitHub, Jenkins is indeed triggered.  I've sent the post-commit hook to [runscope](https://www.runscope.com/) and verified the payload has both the correct git hash and branch name.

Jenkins is set to build the repository url `git@github.mygithubenterpriseurl.com:user/project.git` and all branches (Branch Specifier = `**`)  All other Jenkins SCM settings are their defaults.

Within the build I see these lines:

```
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mygithubenterpriseurl.com:user/project.git
getCandidateRevisions(false,null,,,,remoteUrls=[git@github.mygithubenterpriseurl.com:user/project.git],buildsByBranchName={...snip...},lastBuild=Build #742 of Revision bd40a4956b3f1b6a70552b86bfd6df9a7226dca3 (origin/feature/irrelevant)]) considering branches to build
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/coolness
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/irrelevant
Seen branch in repository origin/release/name
Seen 7 remote branches
Starting with all the branches: [...snip...}
After filtering out what's already been built: [Revision e6a90ad3fa4c02864f36647d77db43721b991992 (origin/feature/irrelevant)]
Checking out Revision e6a90ad3fa4c02864f36647d77db43721b991992 (origin/feature/irrelevant)
```

Once it gets to my build script, I echo `$GIT_HASH` and `$GIT_BRANCH`, and get the wrong stuff: `GIT_HASH=e6a90ad3fa4c02864f36647d77db43721b991992` and `GIT_BRANCH=origin/feature/irrelevant`

When it's done, it builds the latest commit, not the commit specified on the git hash.

Jenkins is v. 1.551, and my list of installed and active Jenkins plugins and versions:

```
active-directory: 1.24
analysis-core: 1.56
ansicolor: 0.3.1
ant: 1.2
build-flow-plugin: 0.10
buildgraph-view: 1.1.1
cobertura: 1.9.5
conditional-buildstep: 1.3.3
config-file-provider: 2.7.4
copy-to-slave: 1.4.3
credentials: 1.10
cvs: 2.11
envfile: 1.2
envinject: 1.89
external-monitor-job: 1.2
ezwall: 0.2
findbugs: 4.56
git-client: 1.8.0
git-parameter: 0.2
git: 2.2.1
github-api: 1.44
github-oauth: 0.14
github: 1.8
ivy: 1.23.2
javadoc: 1.1
jobConfigHistory: 2.6
ldap: 1.8
logstash: 0.8.0
mailer: 1.8
matrix-auth: 1.2
maven-plugin: 2.2
monitoring: 1.50.0
notification: 1.5
nunit: 0.15
pam-auth: 1.1
parameterized-trigger: 2.24
postbuildscript: 0.16
publish-over-ssh: 1.11
pwauth: 0.4
role-strategy: 2.1.0
run-condition: 1.0
scm-api: 0.2
scp: 1.8
sonar: 2.1
ssh-credentials: 1.6.1
ssh-slaves: 1.6
ssh: 2.4
subversion: 2.2
testng-plugin: 1.6
token-macro: 1.10
translation: 1.11
vsphere-cloud: 1.1.6
windows-slaves: 1.0
xunit: 1.84
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this feature doesn't exist.  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24291 is an issue to propose adding it.  https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/GitHubWebHook.java#L175 specifically pulls only the repository url and the committer name from the webhook, and discards the rest of the data ... including the git hash.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't pull requests do what you want? Test the pull request / merge and actually commit and push it, if the build succeeds